# how to run ubuntu 13.10 along windows 8?

Tags: grub2, 13.10, windows-8

i cannot dual boot between 8 and Ubuntu 13.10 ,could anyone have the solution?

after i tried to install Ubuntu in a part ion i cannot see the dual boot menu.now i cannot use 8.please help

Comment: please indicate your BootInfo URL ( https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info )

Answer (score 0):

You have to prepaire Windows as the main system.
Download and install within Windows this:
https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/

Then create wihtin Windows 2 partitions:
1 for You're Linux version. (minimal 10 GB) and
1 for You're Linux swap. It should be as great as You're internal Memory+ 1GB
  In my case 5GB as a swap file/dir/drive...

Make it NTSF primair. Bootup Windows again to check this out. After installing Linux, You don find these drives back.

OK: 
throw in the Linux DVD/CD and startup. Goto manual installation.
Be secure to install everything on the Linux-drives. Don't select the main drive.
(/SDA:) for the Grub install...
After installing bootup You're PC. 
If everything is all right, Windows (7/8) will come up. That's good:
Check out You're drives. Windows won't recocqnize You're Linux-partitions.
That's also good.

Here You have to startup EasyBCD. It will find all the Grub-installations on You're PC.
Give it a New name.  Reboot again.

A selection will apear:
- Windows 7/8 (Standard)
- Linux (New Name)

Of course select Linux. And be amazed how fast it is:
On my ssd within seconds Linux Mint is ready...

Build out the old HD's and build in SSD's. Linux=freedom...
No OEM required...

Greetings and succes with You're Linux installation...